# Failed to install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js, typescript-eslint

I started installing eslint plugins but I found an issue with [@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin).

It requires installing it using `--legacy-peer-deps`, however, this can lead to potential bugs (Accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.)

#### Env:

Next.js version `13.4.8`.

#### Steps:

`npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`.

#### Expected:

The package should be installed.

#### Current:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: credium-gersthofen-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @typescript-eslint/parser@5.62.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm ERR!   @typescript-eslint/parser@"^5.42.0" from eslint-config-next@13.4.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-next
npm ERR!     eslint-config-next@"13.4.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @typescript-eslint/parser@6.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm ERR!   peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^6.0.0 || ^6.0.0-alpha" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@6.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/alaeddine/.npm/_logs/2023-08-03T12_17_06_200Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/alaeddine/.npm/_logs/2023-08-03T12_17_06_200Z-debug-0.log
```

#### package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@types/node": "20.4.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.8",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.19.0",
    "next": "13.4.8",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.3",
    "swr": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

The problem is from `eslint-config-next@13.4.8`. Should I update the npm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explanation

If you create a new project with `npm init -y` and then `npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`, you would see in your `package-lock.json`:

```json
"node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": {
  "version": "6.2.1",
  ...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0 || ^6.0.0-alpha",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

This means `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` version `6.2.1` needs `@typescript-eslint/parser` version `^6.0.0` to be in your project.

Meanwhile, here is what you have in your current `package-lock.json`:

```json
"node_modules/eslint-config-next": {
  "version": "13.4.8",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.42.0",
    ...
  },
  ...
},
```

Meaning `eslint-config-next` needs version `5.42.0`, so while installing `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`, npm founds a versions conflict.

## Solution

You can install `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` version `5.9.0`, which expects the version `^5.0.0` of `@typescript-eslint/parser` :

```
npm i @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.9.0
```

Answer (score 4):

I got a similar issue working with a create-react-app which I was converting to use typescript. As Youssouf suggested, the issue is the conflict of versions between `@typescript-eslint` and some other sub-modules, such as `@typescript-eslint/parser`. This was evident by my package-lock.json listing several `@typescript-eslint` sub-modules as at version 5.6.2.

I fixed this by first running `npm i @typescript-eslint/parser@latest` to upgrade the sub-modules in my package-lock. I was then able to run `npm i @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone uses eslint-config-standard-with-typescript
make sure you pin @typescript-eslint/parser and @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin to the exact same versions in your package-lock.json.

In my case it was:

```
"node_modules/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": {
            "version": "43.0.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript/-/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript-43.0.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-WfZ986+qzIzX6dcr4yGUyVb/l9N3Z8wPXCc5z/70fljs3UbWhhV+WxrfgsqMToRzuuyX9MqZ974pq2UPhDTOcA==",
            "dev": true,
            "dependencies": {
                "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
                "eslint-config-standard": "17.1.0"
            },
            "peerDependencies": {
                "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
                "eslint": "^8.0.1",
                "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
                "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 ",
                "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
                "typescript": "*"
            }
        },
```

After the above adjustment running 'npm install' runs without errors.

Read more on here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript